# How do I change the text of an Element in jsoup?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I'm iterating over an HTML document and changing the text of the elements, but Jsoup is not working when trying to change any of the elements' texts. My code is:

```
            // URL
            String url = "http://example.com/source.html";

            Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url)
                       .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0")
                       .referrer("http://www.google.com") 
                       .ignoreHttpErrors(true).get();

            // Select all of the elements in the HTML
            Elements eles = doc.body().select("*");
            // For each element
            for (Element ele : eles) {

                String text = ele.ownText();
                System.out.println(text);
                ele.text("newText");

            }

            File htmlFile = new File("output.html");
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(htmlFile, "UTF-8");
            // Write our translated HTML to the output file
            pw.println(doc);
            pw.close();
```

And the resulting HTML body that I get is:

```
 <body>
  newText
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're selecting ALL elements in the document using `.select("*")` and the effect is that you replaced the content of the `<body>` as well so everything else is lost. Try to be more specific with selecting elements.

Comment: I want to select all of them so that part is right I guess. Then, I iterate over all the elements and I want to change the text of all of them. Shouldn't it work? Appending new text to old elements' text is actually working so I suppose this should be working too.

Comment: I really doubt you want to select all elements. If you really want then the ouput you get is exactly what I'd expect because `ele.text("newText")` doesn't just "add text" but it replaces whole content of given element with this text.  
It would be much easier if you included fragment of the input HTML and exact example of what you expect.